# passing variable not working

Tags: vb.net, global-variables, parameter-passing

i have asked about passing variables between forms and got answers.  i tested them with a simple form and it worked.  i created a global variable class and a public variable and it seemed to work.  but when i tried the same thing in my actual program. it does not work and i cannot figure out why.

Basically i have a form that displays inventory.  each item has a vatid field. when i click on a button i want it to open the vat form and i choose a different vat id by selecting it from a datagrid. then when i click a select button that vat id must pass back to the already open inventory screen and update the vatid text box for that item.

[view inventory screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltZGX.jpg)

on this screen i want to click on the button next to vatid and it must open a vat form from which i select a vat type

code for this screen is here

```
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class frmviewinventory
    Dim mysqlconn As MySqlConnection
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
    'Public recvatid As Integer

    Private Sub load_table() 'routine to refresh database and reload datagrid

        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=fabpos"
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        ' Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
        Dim bsource As New BindingSource


        Try
            mysqlconn.Open()
            Dim query As String

            query = "select * from fabpos.inventory"
            command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
            sda.SelectCommand = command
            sda.Fill(dbdataset)
            bsource.DataSource = dbdataset
            dginventory.DataSource = bsource
            sda.Update(dbdataset)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader

            mysqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            mysqlconn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnloadgrid.Click
        dbdataset.Clear()
        load_table()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnclose_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnclose.Click

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmviewinventory_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        optdescription.Checked = True
        txtsearch.Select()
        load_table()

        dginventory.Columns.Item(0).Width = 50
        dginventory.Columns.Item(1).Width = 50
        dginventory.Columns.Item(2).Width = 90
        dginventory.Columns.Item(3).Width = 300

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtsearch_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.TextChanged

        Dim dv As New DataView(dbdataset)

        If optstockcode.Checked = True Then

            dv.RowFilter = String.Format("stockcode like '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text)
            dginventory.DataSource = dv

        ElseIf optbarcode.Checked = True Then

            dv.RowFilter = String.Format("barcode like '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text)
            dginventory.DataSource = dv

        ElseIf optdescription.Checked = True Then

            dv.RowFilter = String.Format("description like '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text)
            dginventory.DataSource = dv

        ElseIf optbin.Checked = True Then

            dv.RowFilter = String.Format("binlocation like '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text)
            dginventory.DataSource = dv
        End If

        'dv.RowFilter = String.Format("stockcode like '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text)
        'dginventory.DataSource = dv

    End Sub

    Private Sub optstockcode_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles optstockcode.CheckedChanged
        txtsearch.Select()
    End Sub

    Private Sub optbarcode_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles optbarcode.CheckedChanged
        txtsearch.Select()
    End Sub

    Private Sub optdescription_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles optdescription.CheckedChanged
        txtsearch.Select()
    End Sub

    Private Sub optbin_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles optbin.CheckedChanged
        txtsearch.Select()
    End Sub
    Private Sub frmviewinventory_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape) Then
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub dginventory_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dginventory.SelectionChanged

        Dim i As Integer
        i = dginventory.CurrentRow.Index
        Me.txtid.Text = dginventory.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtstockcode.Text = dginventory.Item(1, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtbarcode.Text = dginventory.Item(2, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtdescription.Text = dginventory.Item(3, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtrecname.Text = dginventory.Item(4, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtvatid.Text = dginventory.Item(5, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtcostexcl.Text = dginventory.Item(6, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtvatamt.Text = dginventory.Item(7, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtcostincl.Text = dginventory.Item(8, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtmu.Text = dginventory.Item(9, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtspexcl.Text = dginventory.Item(10, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtspincl.Text = dginventory.Item(11, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtprofit.Text = dginventory.Item(12, i).Value.ToString
        Me.txtgp.Text = dginventory.Item(13, i).Value.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub btngetvat_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btngetvat.Click

        Dim getvat As New frmvat
        getvat.Show()
        getvat.btnselect.Visible = True

    End Sub

End Class
```

the vat screen is here
[vat form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4vHL.jpg)
code that is supposed to pass the global variable back to the inventory screen

```
 Private Sub dgvat_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvat.SelectionChanged

    Dim i As Integer
    i = dgvat.CurrentRow.Index
    Me.txtvatid.Text = dgvat.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
    Me.txtvatcode.Text = dgvat.Item(1, i).Value.ToString
    Me.txtvatdescription.Text = dgvat.Item(2, i).Value.ToString
    Me.txtvatpercentage.Text = dgvat.Item(3, i).Value.ToString
    globalvariables.vatidvariable = Convert.ToInt32(txtvatid.Text)


End Sub

Private Sub btnselect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnselect.Click

    globalvariables.vatidvariable = Convert.ToInt32(txtvatid.Text)
    frmviewinventory.txtvatid.Text = globalvariables.vatidvariable
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

my public class is here

```
Public Class globalvariables

Public Shared vatidvariable As String
Public Shared testvariable As String


End Class
```

i have tried this on a simple app with just 2 forms and text boxes and it works perfectly.  but here in my actual program it does not. and the vatid still remains the same.

i have checked the readonly properties and enabled properties for the text bosex and they are all fine.  im going grey.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  The first can help avoid DVs on future questions; the second explains how SO works such as what you should do when you get an answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a global variable.  That's dodgy.  The dialogue should make the appropriate data available via a property or method and the caller should retrieve the data from that property of method.  For instance, let's say that `Form1` displays `Form2`, the user enters some text into a `TextBox` on `Form2` and then that text should be displayed in a `Label` on `Form1`:

```
Public Class Form2

    Public ReadOnly Property TextBoxText As String
        Get
            Return TextBox1.Text
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using dialogue As New Form2
            If dialogue.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Label1.Text = dialogue.TextBoxText
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

The property can expose whatever data you want.  It doesn't have to be a property of a control directly.  Also note that this code doesn't include the mechanism for the dialogue to return `OK` or `Cancel`, which is not directly related.

This doesn't answer your question directly but it provides a better mechanism and I couldn't practically include all that code in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your following method is setting the variable incorrectly

```
Private Sub btnselect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnselect.Click

    globalvariables.vatidvariable = Convert.ToInt32(txtvatid.Text)
    '**** The following code line is misleading you
    frmviewinventory.txtvatid.Text = globalvariables.vatidvariable
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Here you are setting the value to a new instance of this form and not the one that opened your vat form. You can directly access the `globalvariables.vatidvariable` on your view inventory screen after the `getvat.Show()` code. More appropriately replace the `getvat.Show()` line with the following

```
 If getvat.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
     txtvatid.Text = globalvariables.vatidvariable
 End If
```

Hope it will work for you.
It could be better done without global variable.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. but im still not understanding.
how do i check if the viewinventory form is open and pass the value back to a textbox in viewinventory form that is open.

also the globalvariables.vatidvariable gets its value from a record that i click in the datagrid of the vat form.  i have to open the vat form first and then choose a vat id

Comment: 1. assign your `vatidvariable` variable in `dgvat_SelectionChanged` event. 2. Your `btnselect_Click` event will just close the form. 3. `btngetvat_Click` event will use `.ShowDialog` method to open the form. Just use the code in this event which i mentioned above in the answer.

Comment: hi, i have tried your code but it still does not work.
in the view inventory screen i open the vat form with the following code
' Dim getvat As New frmvat

        If getvat.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            txtvatid.Text = globalvariables.vatidvariable
            getvat.btnselect.Visible = True
        End If '
in the vat form if just close the vat form withe me.close()
but the txtvatid textbox in view inventory still stays the same.

Comment: hi finally got it working.  i was not setting the dialogresult value to ok in the select button.  did that and it works fine